# What is the pressure-temperature rating for a stainless steel Class 150 nipple?

Tags: piping, pipelines

Which ASME standard defines Class 150 Nipples - material stainless steel? What is the pressure-temperature rating for such a fitting?

[image]

I don't have ASME standards available but I don't believe ASME B16.11 has any mention of double-threaded hexagonal nipples. I am interested especially in pressure/temperature dependence.

Comment: Sometimes folks downvote questions. It hasn't been closed yet so I wouldn't worry too much. In my opinion this is a reasonable question as it _should_ have a clear-cut answer within the engineering domain. Though I don' know what it is :)

Comment: This seems like a pretty simple question of fact that could be answered by purchasing the appropriate standard(s). Why do you need this information? Maybe we can help you with the underlying problem?

Comment: I am doing some pipline for my project with this type of nipple and trying to find out where can I look and where can i find standard with dimensions, pressure rating and pressure/temperature dependecie. Something similar to flanges (depending on material also).